# Selecting a nested div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, computer-science, selector

I am using a polls plugin which generates the following HTML:

```
<div class="pane">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#">Best Local Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="pane"></div>
        <div class="pane"></div>
        <div class="pane"></div>
        <div class="pane"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="pane">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#">MISC tab</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="pane"></div>
        <div class="pane"></div>
        <div class="pane"></div>
        <div class="pane"></div>
    </div>
```

This repeats on and on (depending on how many polls I have). I simply need a jQuery selector to select all of the divs with a class of `pane` that are children of the div class `pane`. (AKA, I need to just select the nested divs with a class of `pane`).

Can somebody help me out with the jquery selector to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or, you may be able to do:

```
$('div.pane > div.pane')
```

Answer (score 2):

This can help you:

```
$(".pane").each(function(){
    if($(this).children().length > 0){
      //Our parent .pane div
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('div.pane div.pane')...
```

Comment: although this is definitely a great solution (for css), @Justin's solution is a better jquery selector.

Answer (score 0):

By using Naveed's example I was able to solve my problem in the following way. Specifically, looping through the elements did the trick:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.rs-gallery-desc').click(function(){ 
        $("ul.rs-gallery-images-list > li").each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
              //console.log($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
              $(this).find('a')[0].click();;
            }
        });
    });         
});
```